# awk: Can I find the occurrence of char in given string?

Tags: shell, awk

Is there any way to get following result?

```
a c a c a c a a a a a a a a c c c a c 0 0 a c 0 a

max a
2nd max c
```

Comment: If no one else writes it up, awk has associative arrays and a sort function-- all internal.

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
echo "a c a c a c a a a a a a a a c c c a c 0 0 a c 0 a"|tr " " "\n"|sort|uniq -c|sort -rn
```

1. We use `tr` to convert the spaces to newlines, then
2. use `sort` to sort the data (which is now a series of lines) alphabetically, then
3. use `uniq` to count how many there are of each, and lastly
4. use `sort` again to change the order of appearance to descending (with max occurrences first).

It assumes that each item is separated by a single space (which is true in your example).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
echo "i u v w a c a c a c a a a a a a a a c c c a c 0 0 a c 0 a"|
  awk 'BEGIN { RS=" " ; } 
       {a[$1]++;} 
       END { 
           PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" ;
           asorti(a,b) ; 
          i = 1 ; 
          for (aa in a ) {
              printf "%d : %s =%d\n",i++,aa,a[aa] ;
              if ( i == 3 ) exit ;} }'
```

(can be onelined )

where

- `BEGIN { RS=" " ; }` set field separator
- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" ;` sort according to array's value

you can add  `for (aa in a ) printf "a[%s]=%d\n",aa,a[aa] ;` before `PROCINFO` to see actual array order before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If it must be `awk` (`file` contains the "string"):

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} {a[$1]++} END{for(i in a){if(a[i]>m){m=a[i];f=i}else 
  if(a[i]>n){n=a[i];s=i}}print "max:",f,"\n2nd max:",s}' file
```

---

- `BEGIN{RS=" "}` sets the row separator of `awk` to space.
- `a[$1]++` fills an array `a` with the values as indexed and the number of occurences as values.
- `END{...}` The END block is executed after all lines are processed.

  - `for(i in a)` loops trough the array `a`.
  - `if(a[i]>m)` if the value is greater than `m` then...
  - `m=a[i];f=i` `m` is set to that value and `f` to the string. This way we find the maximum value
  - `else if(a[i]>n){...}`: now we do the same again for the 2nd max value and save it to the variable `s`.
- `print ...` In the end, print the ouput in the desired format.

---

The output:

```
max: a
2nd max: c
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to reach for ruby here:

```
echo "a c a c a c a a a a a a a a c c c a c 0 0 a c 0 a" |
ruby -e '
  max = STDIN.gets                                # read the line
             .split                               # split on whitespace
             .group_by {|elem| elem}              # create a hash grouping the words
             .to_a                                # convert has to array of [key,value] pairs
             .map {|key, val| [key, val.length]}  # convert to array of [key, count] pairs
             .sort_by {|key, count| count}        # sort numerically
             .reverse                             # in descending order
  puts "max: " + max[0][0]
  puts "2nd max: " + max[1][0]
'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `perl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count_of;
#split the first line of input on whitespace - count each element. 
$count_of{$_}++ for split (' ', <> ); 

#sort by count, print in order. 
foreach my $letter ( 
    sort { $count_of{$b} <=> $count_of{$a} } 
        keys %count_of ) {
    print $count_of{$letter}, " => ", $letter,"\n";
}
```

This can one-liner-ify as:

```
perl -lne '$c{$_}++ for split; END{print join ( "\n", (sort{$c{$b}<=>$c{$a}} keys %c )[0,1])}'
```